# reference for attributes of <a> tag

Tags: javascript

I found this [mdn document](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/A) for the a tag but it does not list the hostname attribute.  Where can I get info. on this?  This is an attribute/property of the anchor object correct?  And why the hell is this thing called an anchor instead of a link?  That's what it is..a hyperlink.  Getting frustated with finding documentation...maybe I just overlooked it...actually I ran a search for hostname and no go.

Basically if I have

```
  b=document.createElement('a')
  b.href=c[2].value;
```

I can access

```
b.hostname
```

but I need documention for this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mdn is not the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html#url-decomposition-idl-attributes), which does mention the [`hostname` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html#url-decomposition-idl-attributes).

An `<a>` element is usually a link (i.e. its `href` property is set). However, you can also use it as an anchor, as in:

```
<a href="#bottom">Bottom</a>
<a name="bottom">This is an anchor</a>
```

This functionality is obsolete; you can now set the `id` attribute of *any* element instead:

```
<a href="#bottom">Bottom</a>
<div id="bottom">This is an anchor</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question.  thanks for the explanation of why it is called anchor i.e. the linking part is not the primary purpose though it seems to be the most used.

Comment: @naveen I didn't dispute that, but it's apparently not good when it comes to the `hostname` attribute ;)

Comment: @Chris Aaker Follow the [link to `hostname` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html#url-decomposition-idl-attributes) in this answer to get to the official documentation. Bear in mind that most browsers don't support these new and exotic attributes yet. Chrome does.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that MDN isn't a normative reference. @naveen - the MDN documentation is a wiki that anyone can contribute to. While it's useful, it should only be quoted as a supplementary reference or for Gecko-only properties and methods. Where W3C DOM objects and properties are concerned, the relevant W3C standard (or draft in the case of HTML5) should be referenced first.

Comment: @Chris Aaker In the standard. As RobG points out nicely, the HTML standard is the normative reference.

Comment: sound good I'll check the normative reference along with mdn for supplementary... thanks

Comment: @phihag: +1. very nice find. didn't knew that a element also supports the complement of URL decomposition IDL attributes. i stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It's a property of the [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location#Location_object).

As about the name of the `<a>` (anchor) tag, I'm not an English native speak but a link has two ends and it seems that *anchor* refers to any of them:

http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/struct/links.html

There's only one tag to define both ends and that's the name they chose.

Comment: that was my thought initially. try this `var b=document.createElement('a'); alert(b.hostname)` it shows the desired result from spec. "These must follow the rules given for URL decomposition IDL attributes, with the input being the result of resolving the element's href attribute relative to the element, if there is such an attribute and resolving it is successful, or the empty string otherwise; and the common setter action being the same as setting the element's href attribute to the new output value."